# prove Complicated Integral.

Tags: integration

please How can I prove that
$$
e^{bt} \ \int_0^t \ f(s) ds=\int_0^t \ ( e^{-bs} \ f(s)-be^{-bs}\int_0^s\ f(u)\ du) \ ds
$$ 
f non-negative  measurable function

best, Educ

Comment: You can get appropriately sized parentheses (and other paired delimiters) by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: Thank you that's help me in Kile software

Answer (score 1):

Integrate the second term on the right-hand side by parts (integrating $b\mathrm e^{-bs}$ and differentiating the inner integral). The boundary term yields the left-hand side, and the integral term cancels the first term on the right-hand side.

Comment: Could you please explain that to me in the formal math  i'll be grateful to help me

Comment: @Educ: I'm afraid you'll first have to explain to me what "formal math" is :-) Are "integrate", "differentiate", "boundary term" etc. not formal math terms?

Comment: not in words i mean in formal math terms  Thanks for your time dear professor  best Educ

Comment: @Educ: I'm not a professor :-) I'm not sure I understand -- isn't "terms" another word for "words"? Perhaps you mean you want me to write formulas?

Answer (score 0):

Anyway Thank Mr joriki

so we know that : 
$$(fg)'=  f'(s).g(s)ds +f(s).g'(s)ds $$
$$\int_0^t(fg)'=(fg)= \int_0^t \ f'(s).g(s)ds +\int_0^tf(s).g'(s)ds$$
so we use that for the left-side term :
$$ e^{-bt} \ \int_0^t \ f(s)ds$$ with $u(s)=e^{-bs}, v(s)=\int_0^s f(u)du ,u'(s)=-be^{-bs},v'(s)=f(s)ds$
now it's easy to see :
$e^{-bt} \ \int_0^t \ f(s)ds=u(t)v(t)=\int_0^t \ u'(s).v(s)ds +\int_0^tu(s).v'(s)ds=\int_0^t \ ( e^{-bs} \ f(s)-be^{-bs}\int_0^s\ f(u)\ du) \ ds$
you see Mr Mr joriki what i mean by formula
best regrads , Educ